# How to run 'svm-predict.exe' of LIBSVM when test data is not labeled?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, svm, libsvm

I am trying to use [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for classifying handwritten characters. I have successfully executed **'svm-train.exe'** for training and **'svm-predict.exe'** for testing. For both, the input file format is-

```
0 1:1 2:0 3:1 4:0
1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1
0 1:1 2:0 3:1 4:1
1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1
```

Now, I want to classify unlabeled data with **'svm-predict.exe'**. So, now the input file will be like this-

```
1:1 2:0 3:1 4:0
1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1
1:1 2:0 3:1 4:1
1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1
```

But, when I run **'svm-predict.exe'** with above input, following *error* is shown-

> Wrong input format at line 1

It means- I cannot give unlabeled data to **'svm-predict.exe'**. Then how I suppose to use it in real-world application, where I want to label unlabeled data? I have googled and also asked others but got no helpful solution.

**Remarks:** An advice I got was- to label test data with any random value (as I did not need the accuracy). But that did not seem logical to me. Is there any straight forward method to do it?

Comment: svm-predict.exe is only for "playing" around and not for real-world application. Best way would be to use the library and write some own code.

Comment: Really !?!?! But I saw people using it! @rzo

Comment: 'svm-predict.exe' is written for evaluation purpose (target: accuracy). If you just want to predict unlabeled data, you will need to rewrite the input parser...

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use 'svm-predict.exe' without *label*? @rzo

Comment: Yes. Or you use random labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the answer is- **No, 'svm-predict.exe' cannot be used without *label***. The 'executable' is not designed for *real world use*, as [rzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4506678/rzo) commented-

> svm-predict.exe is only for "playing" around and not for real-world application. Best way would be to use the library and write some own code.

But, if we want to simply use it for *demonstration* or *avoid complexity* of programming, then there is no other way but to use 'random labels'.

For using [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) library in a project, you may visit here-

- [C](http://jamescpoole.com/2012/10/30/libsvm-tutorial-part-1-overview/)
- [C#](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/svm-tutorial-classify-text-csharp/)
- [Java1](http://ask.osify.com/qa/311), [Java2](https://sourceforge.net/p/java-ml/java-ml-code/ci/30237db0cb0457fe2629004ac91ac4cd2768d8ea/tree/src/tutorials/classification/TutorialLibSVM.java#l31)
- [MATLAB](https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/libsvm_matlab)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "svm-predict.exe" with 'test','model' and 'out' files. 
Let's assume your train file -> abc.train and your test file -> abc.test.
When you execute "svm-train.exe abc.train" in cmd, it will create "abc.train.model" file in the current directory.
In order to predict, you need to execute "svm-predict.exe abc.test abc.train.model abc.out" in cmd. Don not worry about "abc.out",it will be generated automatically.
PS:In test file, you need to describe classes for lines like you do in train file.
It will print result classes on abc.out and give accuracy by comparing out and test files.